# Change view dynamically in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, forms, angularjs

I am trying to create a form builder in AngularJS. The whole form structure is defined in a JSON object like this:

```
form = {
  "title": "Some form title",          // Title of the field
  "fieldsets": [                       // Each form is composed of several fieldsets 
    {
      "title": "First fieldset",       // Title of the fieldset
      "fields": [                      // Each fieldset is composed of several fields
        {
          "title": "First field",      // Title of the field, displayed in a label
          "type": "text"               // Type of the field which determines which partial to load
        },
        {
          "title": "Second field",
          "type": "date"
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Second fieldset",
      "fields": [
        {
          "title": "First field",
          "type": "text"
        },
        {
          "title": "Second field",
          "type": "date"
        },
      ]
    }     
   ]
}
```

I get a JSON object like the one above and then render it in a page like this (jade template):

```
h5 {{ form.title }}
div(ng-repeat="fs in form.fieldsets")
  fieldset
    legend {{ fs.title }}
    div(ng-repeat="field in fs.fields")
      myfield(field="field")
```

`myfield` is a custom directive which parses each field and based on the type, renders a different partial. Here is the code:

```
var appFilters = angular.module('appComponents', []);
appFilters.directive('myfield', ['$compile', '$http', '$templateCache', function($compile, $http, $templateCache){
  var getTemplate = function(contentType) {
    return $http.get('partials/' + contentType + '_field', {cache: $templateCache});
    // I get the partials here, for example for a field of type text, I load text_field.jade
  };

  var linker = function(scope, element, attrs){

    scope.edit_field = function(field) {
      field.type = "template";
    };

    var loader = getTemplate(scope.field.type);

    var promise = loader.success(function(html) {
      element.html(html);
    }).then(function(response) {
      element.replaceWith($compile(element.html())(scope));
    });
  };

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      field:'='
    },
    link: linker
  };
}]);
```

I have several partials. They all inherit from one base template, named `field.jade`. Here is the base template and another one that inherits from it:

**field.jade:** (base template for other partials):

```
div
  block _title

div
  div
    block _label
      label {{ field.title }}:
  div
    block _field
  div
    block _controls
      a.control(ng-click="edit_field(field)") Edit
```

**text_field.jade:** (partial for the fields of type text)

```
extend field

block _field
  input(type="text")
```

**template_field.jade:** (partial for the fields, when they are in edit mode)

```
extend field

block _label
  input(type="text", ng-model="field.title")
  // The user can edit the field label here

block _field
  select
  // Here the user can select from several different field types
```

Now when the user clicks the `Edit` button, `field.type` is changed to `template` and I want AngularJS to load the `template_field.jade` view instead of the main view (like `text_field.jade`).

Does anyone have any idea how to tell AngularJS to reload the `templated_field.jade` partial instead?

P.S: I wanted to create a fiddle for this, but since it was too complicated and I had to import several different files for it to run, I gave up creating the fiddle.

Comment: Think you need to add more code here. Maybe a fiddle?

Comment: @Baszz I added more detail here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way around it. It works fine, but I am not sure if it's the best way to do it. In my `edit_field` function, I need to call the `linker` function manually.

```
scope.edit_field = function(field) {
  field.type = "template";
  linker(scope, element, attrs);
};
```

And also, I had to replace the call to `replaceWith()` with `html()`, because, I don't know why, but `replaceWith()` only works the first time it is called.
So, this line:

```
element.replaceWith($compile(element.html())(scope));
```

should be replaced with this:

```
element.html($compile(element.html())(scope));
```

And the final code is:

```
var appFilters = angular.module('appComponents', []);
appFilters.directive('myfield', ['$compile', '$http', '$templateCache', function($compile, $http, $templateCache){
  var getTemplate = function(contentType) {
    return $http.get('partials/' + contentType + '_field', {cache: $templateCache});
    // I get the partials here, for example for a field of type text, I load text_field.jade
  };

  var linker = function(scope, element, attrs){

    scope.edit_field = function(field) {
      field.type = "template";
      linker(scope, element, attrs);
    };

    var loader = getTemplate(scope.field.type);

    var promise = loader.success(function(html) {
      element.html(html);
    }).then(function(response) {
      element.html($compile(element.html())(scope));
    });
  };

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      field:'='
    },
    link: linker
  };
}]);
```

Please correct me if I am making any mistakes here.